# Does adding RAM as being part of a set matter?

Tags: memory

I’m currently running 6GB of RAM: 2GB x 3 sticks on a Windows 10 (64bit) on an Asus P6T SE motherboard that has 6 slots for RAM, and found some matching RAM online the other day for cheap.

The speed, size, everything matches what I have now. The only difference is the sets I found are 2 sets of 2GB x 2 instead of 2GB x 3. Will this matter?

I’m only planning on installing 3 sticks and they are the same as my existing sticks other than this.

Comment: For desktop ram, No. What matters is the number of channels on the motherboard/chipset/cpu combination, and that the chips are installed in dual or triple channel (depending on which your hardware supports) configuration. consult your motherboard manual for exact instructions, but since you are filling all slots with sticks of the same size and speed, it should just work. One other thing to check is the voltage of the chips. that MUST match.  Server ram is more complicated, with Ranks and whatnot, but for desktops its pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

That particular unit has Triple Channel Architecture. Installing an even number doesn't affect speed all that much, but there is a slight performance hit for installing in groups other than 3.

One option would be to buy 2 pairs, install 3 and keep one as a spare.

Also it won't matter if they are different from the other 3 installed in the system if they are the same speed. The different channels are handled separately.

Comment: "One option would be to buy 2 pairs, install 3 and keep one as a spare."  That was exactly my plan. I will check again to make sure the voltage is the same, but I'm almost positive it it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect it wouldn't work at all.  You **say** everything is the same but I think you missed something--since your current memory is a set of three that says you most likely have a triple channel architecture.  Selling triple channel chips in a set of two makes little sense.

Comment: Nothing about a ram chip affects the way it is or isn't channeled, so bundling chips in packs of two or three is just marketing; not engineering. It doesn't really matter how they are packaged so long as the op has a multiple of 3 for triple channel or a multiple of 2 for double channel, and luckily, 6 is both. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Ganged_versus_unganged